# adults’ English teacher or adult’s English teacher?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

In this sentence, “I would like to apply for the post of adults’ English teacher,” do you say “adults’ English teacher” or “adult’s English teacher”? 
If this sentence is totally wrong, could you paraphrase the sentence in a way that the meaning remains?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can side-step the awkwardness by writing "I teach English to adults." Of course if you *say* it, there is no apostrophe evident.

Comment: It would be a bit crass to say *I teach English to foreigners*, so I'd suggest *I teach English **in adult education***. But I can't see any obvious and simple way of distinguishing between whether you mean teaching *native Anglophones* how to read and write (because for some reason they didn't learn these basic skills at school, which would often imply some kind of "special needs"), or because they don't actually *know* enough English (particularly, *spoken* English) to get by.

Comment: You probably want an answer "A (or B) is the correct way to **write** this." But neither is ungrammatical, and while the plural possessive probably shades it on the grounds of logic, both look ungainly (and that can be as real a factor as ungrammaticality). There is even, as association rather than possession is indicated,  quite a strong argument for the plural-form  attributive usage (“I am an adults English teacher"), in line with 'X Working Mens Club'; 'Y Writers Guild' (qv) and the like. But Weather Vane and FF give sound advice.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, I can change the order in some way, but actually I wanna write this sentence: “I would like to apply for the post of adults’ English teacher.” Any suggestions for paraphrasing?

Comment: An [English teacher for adults](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22English+teacher+for+adults%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNSuH0ouLir6sgHH2SDKxo6CTnMxFg:1567796668639&ei=vK1yXZPNJoX8kwWbzJrICQ&start=40&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiTm47c8bzkAhUF_qQKHRumBpk4FBDy0wMIywE&biw=1303&bih=647)

Comment: I'd paraphrase this as nothing but "English teacher". The ambiguity between *adults English" and "adults teacher" shows there has to be an equivalence between both for the whole set "adults english teacher" to work. But this is discriminatory and just wrong. There is a limited sense in which the discrimination works, but not in favor of the "adults". The phrase *ESL-teacher, English as a second language* implies age 4 and up, at least. It seems from the comments that *for adults* is the prefered paraphrase.

Comment: @vectory that's like saying menswear shops are discriminating against women and children. There are schools that specialise in teaching English to adults who already speak it fairly well but who want to be fluent. How is this discriminatory? If someone's job is teaching adults, why should they not say so?

Comment: It's not clear what you're even asking.  "I'm an adult's English teacher" would mean that you're the English of some adult. "I am an adults’ English teacher" and "I am an adult’s English teacher" aren't grammatical, or at the very least aren't idiomatic.  "I'm an adult English teacher" would be what you would say if you are an English teacher who is an adult.  "I'm an adult-English teacher" would be what you would say if you teach English in an adult-education program (i.e., you're teaching an adult-English class, an English class for adults).

Comment: @WeatherVan while the point is arguable, the equivalence *mens wear* and *mens shop* should be quite clear. It is not clear cut, and the social issue is part of an ongoing debate for over a decade. You picked a dicy yet innocious example. Whatever the validity of the term men giving it as much leaway as possible, we can probably agree that *mens wear*, *wear shop* and perhaps even *mens shop* are well meaningful. However *adults english* is dubious; *adults teacher* almost an oxymoron. Baring that, a *mens shop* is not where men are sold and the plural, short of dativ *mannen* (cp *sunnendag*)

Comment: @vectory excuse me but you seem to be talking nonsense. I wrote "menswear shop" which has absolutely no ambiguity or confusion. It sells men's clothing, which anyone can buy there.

Comment: @Weather Vane There's also at least one English lang. website intended for proficient users and linguists, and not those seeking answers to the more basic questions which we all start off with. Allegedly. (Though this question, though addressed here before, is not in that category.)

Comment: OP has edited his question since and my comment is based on this: *I would like to apply for the adult English teacher post*

Answer (score 1):

Use neither. On the one hand, this is the literal difference between the two:

> I am an adult's English teacher

suggests that you are a teacher to one adult;

> I am an adults' English teacher

suggests that you teach multiple adults.

On the other hand, these sentences are both awkward. Possessives tend to work less well when long phrases are involved. In this case, it can become less clear what the possessive is determining: is the subject you teach "adult('s/s') English" or "English"?  There are a few strategies for avoiding the extra awkwardness of the possessive:

1. Use a noun adjunct. "I am an adult English teacher." It still has ambiguity, namely whether you are an adult who teaches English or whether you teach English to adults, but my top [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adult%20english%20teacher%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-e) turn up job ads for the latter. That collocation avoids the possessive entirely.
2. Verb the noun. Make *teacher* into *teach* and explain what you do after that. "I teach English to adult learners" or "I teach English to adults" would explain what you do. A couple of [my first search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20teach%20English%20to%20adults%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-e) link to TEFL teachers who describe themselves in exactly this way.
3. Distinguish your audience in a prepositional phrase. "I am an English teacher for adult learners" or "I am an English teacher for adults." If it is important you say *teacher*, this breaks up the information in a way that makes *adults* more proximal to *teacher* than *English*, and uses *for* to disambiguate the purpose.

Comment: everybody seems to recommend *for*,and in German I'd agree, "für", but why not *to*, "I'm a ... to you", "I am teaching English to adults" ... oh, I see, "\* I'm an English to adults teacher" (not idiomatic at all), but "For adults I am teaching English". This separates "English" and "adults" as far as possible.

Comment: If someone is applying for a post, that post must have been advertised. What does the advertisement call it?

Comment: The advertisement is not in English.